# E: The package libreoffice6.2-debian-menus needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management, libreoffice

I keep getting this error message
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.
I downloaded the latest stable deb version of LibreOffice 6.2.6 ran install and

```
E: The package libreoffice6.2-debian-menus needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

I've tried fixing broken packages, updating, complete removal using package manager but nothing has worked.
My backup won't even work now.
Opening Synaptic I get this

```
E: The package libreoffice6.2-debian-menus needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
E: Internal error opening cache (1). Please report.
```

Then Package manager shuts down

Comment: The package `libreoffice6.2-debian-menus` is not from Ubuntu. Seems like there is more to your story, and you are omitting important details. Please edit your question to tell a more complete story so we can offer useful advice.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 steps to take to get to the current version  of LibreOffice 6 which I have completed in 18.04 (and 16.04) without problems.

1. Add the [LibreOffice PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). Open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
   ```
2. Update your system by running this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Finally run this command in terminal to upgrade or install LibreOffice

   ```
   sudo apt install libreoffice
   ```

Then as any updates are available, they will be automatically offered according to your preferences in Software Updater.

Comment: Hi.Many thanks for the quick response. 
this happens
Reading state information... Done
73 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
 sudo apt install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libreoffice6.2-debian-menus needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
 So nochange. I do see 2 versions of libreoffice in my menu now the 6.2 one that does not work and this following one that does work: Version: 6.0.7.3
Build ID: 1:6.0.7-0ubuntu0.18.04.8

Comment: Ok. I reran the deb install for the downloaded libreoffice 6.2 and it seemed to install fine.
Then I ran fix broken install and this worked fine - returning lists of 29 to upgrade, 10 to newly install, 40 to remove and 44 not to upgrade.
47 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 117 MB of archives.
After this operation, 245 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
I clicked 'Y' and everything ran smoothly.
LibreOffice updated to 6.3.0.4
Many thanks for all your help

Comment: Great stuff! It would be handy if you would kindly accept the answer so that anyone else with the same problem can find the solution quickly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I installed the repository: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

I then reran the deb install for the downloaded libreoffice 6.2 and it seemed to install fine. Then I ran fix broken install and this worked fine - returning lists of 29 to upgrade, 10 to newly install, 40 to remove and 44 not to upgrade. 47 not fully installed or removed. Need to get 117 MB of archives. After this operation, 245 MB disk space will be freed. Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y I clicked 'Y' and everything ran smoothly. LibreOffice updated to 6.3.0.4 Many thanks for all your help