# Unable to install Libreoffice on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, libreoffice

I purged my libreoffice, but then unable to install libreoffice again on my Ubunut 16.04 system.

Below is the error. Please help. Let me know if anything else is needed form my side.

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice : Depends: libreoffice-base but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-calc but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.3.1~rc1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1~lo6) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-draw but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-impress but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-math but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-report-builder-bin but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libreoffice-writer but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-uno (>= 4.4.0~beta2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: fonts-noto-core but it is not installable
               Recommends: fonts-noto-ui-core but it is not installable
               Recommends: libreoffice-gnome but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-nlpsolver but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-report-builder but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-bsh but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-js but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-script-provider-python but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-mysql but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: libreoffice-wiki-publisher but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did some research and finally got stuck on the below error. Please help.

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-core 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**sudo apt-cache policy**

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=vscode stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=vscode stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main i386 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=i386
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=TeamViewer GmbH,a=stable,l=TeamViewer,c=main,b=amd64
     origin linux.teamviewer.com
 500 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=. stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=. stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin repo.skype.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-nilarimogard-webupd8,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=WebUpd8,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-nilarimogard-webupd8,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=WebUpd8,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-nathan-renniewaldock-flux,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=f.lux GUI,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-nathan-renniewaldock-flux,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=f.lux GUI,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=LibreOffice Fresh,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=LibreOffice Fresh,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice-libreoffice-prereleases,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=LibreOffice Pre-Releases,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/libreoffice-prereleases/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-libreoffice-libreoffice-prereleases,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=LibreOffice Pre-Releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib i386 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=xenial,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib,b=i386
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial/contrib amd64 Packages
     release o=Oracle Corporation,n=xenial,l=Oracle Corporation,c=contrib,b=amd64
     origin download.virtualbox.org
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-security,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-backports,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial-updates,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=Ubuntu,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin in.archive.ubuntu.com
Pinned packages:
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo apt update and/or sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: @Mitch, yes I tried both the commands. But nothing worked for me.

Comment: maybe this answer I gave to an earlier issue will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167248/e-the-package-libreoffice6-2-debian-menus-needs-to-be-reinstalled-but-i-cant/1167252#1167252

Comment: The libreoffice you are trying to install is not the Ubuntu packaged one, so providing your source would be helpful (ie. `apt-cache policy`) as the package libstdc++6 to be installed matches Ubuntu sources https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libstdc%2B%2B6 , https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libreoffice-core  ie. you have a sources issue...

Comment: None of it worked for me. I don't know it's showing the same error.

Comment: I downloaded libreoffice debs form its official website and did `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` and the libreoffice installed successfully. How come this is possible?

Comment: so the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Try using snap to install Libre Office ([website link](https://snapcraft.io/libreoffice)). I think the snap version is more up-to-date.

```
$ sudo snap install libreoffice
```

If you still want to use apt, then do this. In your error message, we can see a dependency error. So 1st you have to install those dependencies. For example, your error says `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) ... ...`
So you should do this: `$ sudo apt install libstdc++6`. After that, you may get similar error messages for other dependencies. Install them as well. Finally, when all dependencies are met, you should be able to install libre office via apt. Good luck.

Comment: I purged all libreoffice packages and execute `sudo snap install libreoffice` and it worked for me.